# How do I reset a UIView's position after a CATransform3D?

Tags: ios, uiview, gyroscope, catransform3d

I have a UIView whose perspective I'd like to slightly change as the user rotates his device. For example when the user tilts to the right, I want the left side of the view to 'rise' while the right size 'goes in' but only to a certain point.
Here is my code so far:

```
var dynamicTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
        dynamicTransform.m34 = 1/(-500)

        // Device Tilt
        if motionManager.gyroAvailable {
            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1/30
            motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
            motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), withHandler: { (gyroData, NSError) -> Void in
                // Perspective Transform
                dynamicTransform = CATransform3DRotate(dynamicTransform, CGFloat(Double(gyroData!.rotationRate.y) * M_PI / 1080.0), 0, 0.1, 0)
                dynamicTransform = CATransform3DRotate(dynamicTransform, -CGFloat(Double(gyroData!.rotationRate.x) * M_PI / 1080.0), 0.1, 0, 0)
                self.blueView.layer.transform = dynamicTransform
            })
```

Everything works great except for a few caveats:

1) When I return to the device's original orientation as when the device was launched, the view is distorted (i.e.there's still a perspective applied to it). There's probably something wrong with my logic but I don't see what..

2) Sometimes the view rotates clockwise/counterclockwise and doesn't remain still.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send `layoutIfNeeded` to the parent view to force a re-layout after your orientation change?

Comment: How would that be useful?